# should I continue the iteration of psiblast if the blast step produced only below threshold sequences?

Tags: psi-blast, blastp

I used a PSIBLAST (position specific scoring) to detect the similarities between specific proteins and the database of Clostridium.

The results did not reveal any similarities above the e value threshold of 0.001.

Could I continue iterations of the second and third round of PSIBLAST?